# How to use `Array#map` within `Promise.all` in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, promise

I am trying to create a `Promise.all` with an array of items. So if I create it like this it works fine

```
Promise.all([
  Query.getStuff(items[0]),
  Query.getStuff(items[1])
]).then(result => console.log(result))
```

If I try to create the `Promise.all` like this, it doesn't work

```
Promise.all([
    items.map(item => Query.getStuff(item))
]).then(result => console.log(result))
```

The `then` block is run before the `Query.getStuff(item)`.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You should be writing

```
Promise.all(items.map(...))
```

instead of

```
Promise.all([ items.map(...) ])
```

[`Array#map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) returns an array, which means that the way you wrote your code originally, you were actually passing a multidimensional array to `Promise.all` — as in  `[ [promise1, promise2, ...] ]` — instead of the expected one-dimensional version `[promise1, promise2, ...]`.

---

### Revised Code:

```
Promise.all(
    items.map(item => Query.getStuff(item))
).then(result => console.log(result))
```

Comment: What is result. Is it an array?

Comment: Yes @Gilboot the result is an array in the same order as the array provided. `const resultArray = await Promise.all(items.map(...))`